# openMP enviroment settings

Tags: windows-10, openmp

I have a perhaps simple question, but have not found an answer.
Question: Is it possible to set openMP enviroment settings after compiling?   In the source code they are not set.
Question 2: Is there a difference if I use /libs:static or .dll?

I want to use openMP with the following hardware:
2 CPU's ( 2 socket)
each CPU has 12 cores and 24 threads
My solution is:

```
set OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
set OMP_PLACES="{0,1,2,3,4,5}{6,7,8,9,10,11}"
set OMP_PROC_BIND=spread
```

he performance is not good, both CPU's are not used. I use windows 10.

Thanks for a short answer.

Comment: I can't give you a short answer because you don't mention which compiler you are using.

Comment: Environment variable are used to setup the environment, indeed. `OMP_PLACES` is not valid here as a missing comma must be added between the brackets. Use `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE` to check the parameters. Beside this your configuration of `OMP_PLACES` do something you may not want: you define only two places for 12 threads. Please read carefully [the documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse53.html).

Comment: ... and in my experience, linking static or dynamic makes no difference.

Comment: The OpenMP environment variables, if implemented, are read at entry to a parallel region.  libgomp, at least the versions I've used, ignores OMP_PLACES and OMP_PROC_BIND on Windows.  OpenMP Windows implementations I've used which do implement affinity take much longer than linux for it to take effect, so you won't see much benefit on shorter parallel regions.  Without OMP_PLACES, even if hyperthreading is disabled, you can't scale to the full number of cores.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft's compiler it probably doesn't support OMP_PLACES or OMP_PROC_BIND, since it only supports OpenMP 2.0 by default, and those are later features. (They do now seem to be working to upgrade https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/improved-openmp-support-for-cpp-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Hallo, I used Intel FTN new version 2021.1 64 bit on windows 10. I have now found the option in Task Manager to show all logical processors. I now see that my application uses all logical processors.   For me now the question arises, can one optimize then still further? Is it really the case that OMP_PLACES and OMP_PROC_BIND cannot be used on Windows systems?
The initial question in my project was to find compiler options, so that the computation time is almost halved. I did not find this factor of two!  Can someone say from his experience if something like this has ever been achieved?